# Is there a way to receive a message from SQS boto3 where the value of a certain attribute is the one we specify?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, search, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue, and I want to query it and receive a message from it where a certain parameter of the message = x. If it's equal to x, I want to receive all messages where that parameter = x. I haven't been able to find a way to do that, please help.

To give an example. I have an SQS queue where the messages have first name and age. I want all messages where the first name = Alicia. How do I do that using receive_message?

Comment: Do you have any sample code or additional context?

Comment: @DBA108642  suppose I have an SQS queue with messages that contain name and age. How do I get all the messages where the first name = Alicia?

Comment: ok, but how are you accessing this queue? is it saved as a list of messages? you can access individual messages using the `retrieve_message()` function. If you have a list of messages you can just loop through them and append the ones that meet the criteria to a new list

Comment: @DBA108642 Is there a way to retrieve it through receive_message? I don't want to fetch all the messages and then search since that is not optimal

Comment: Here are the docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message

Comment: I recommend seeing if you can call the `receive_message()` method and only retain ones that meet your criteria but you're going to have to go through each message no matter what

Comment: I've read the documentation obviously from multiple sites that's why I asked the question here. Yes I understand now I will have to go through each message and can't query with values. Thanks.